# Why is there の between 考えて and こと in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

Consider the following dialogue.

> A: ダイエットするのは、健康を考えてのことでしょうか。
>
> B: 健康を考えてのことというよりむしろ、…

Why is there の between 考えて (not a noun) and こと (noun) in this sentence?

Answer (score 4):

Adding to what AJFB said, it's a somewhat limited form (different from についての etc) that expresses a type of condition:

ＡてのＢ　≒　Ａ⇒Ｂ (A is the condition needed for B to happen)

You can also insert a こそ after the て to add a touch more emphasis, but maintain more or less the same meaning.

見ての楽しみ (look / see ⇒ enjoy) typically, something like "just wait and see".

> どうなるかは見てのお楽しみです 
> I can't wait to see how things turn out.

健康を考えてのこと

lit. something that is a result of having thought of [subject]'s health

> A: ダイエットするのは、健康を考えてのことでしょうか。
>   Could it be that people diet because they are concerned about their health?
>   B: 健康を考えてのことというよりむしろ、…
>   More than from thinking of their health, I'd say...

No idea who these two are talking about though -- people in general, B, or someone else.

Answer (score 3):

It's not all that uncommon for the て for to be followed by の. In idiomatic uses such as について (e.g. 魚についての本, a book about fish) it's common, but you're seeing a similar thing here. を考えての means 'about' but from a more subjective point of view. Is dieting all about health? (Is it from considering one's health?)